# ServiceNow REST API Integration: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, httprequest, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I tried do some integration towards serviceNow records using python script and referring example given in this link to update the records using Http Request Patch method: [Table API Python](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_TableAPIPythonExamples.html)

Here is my code:

```
#Need to install requests package for python
#sudo easy_install requests
import requests

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://instance.owndomain.com/api/now/table/sc_req_item/2a2851fe88709010b9120e9b506dd9a9'
user = 'username'
pwd = 'password'

# Set proper headers
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.patch(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers ,data='{"u_switch_status_automation":"In Processing using Python", "u_switch_description":"The Automation currently processing this SR using Python"}')

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200: 
  print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:',response.json())
  exit()

 # Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
print('Status:',response.status_code,'Headers:',response.headers,'Response:',response.json())
```

And the result I got is as follows:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1004: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'instance.owndomain.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/automation/switchConf/updateRecord.py", line 18, in <module>
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:',response.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: first see `print( response.text )` - it seems you get something different then JSON. Maybe you get normal text or HTML with warning or error message which can help you .

Comment: BTW: you can use `patch( ... json={"u_switch_status_automation": "In Processing using Python", "u_switch_description": "The Automation currently processing this SR using Python"})` and it should convert it to JSON string. And it should also add header `{"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}`  automatically - so you don't have to add it manually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur comment. I tried use the latest python version, python3..8.3. The result returning the 403 Code which means Forbidden. Means there is some restriction on the Targeted Server side, right?

Comment: 403 means some restriction - and usually it means wrong data in request. And it doesn't matter what python version you use. You should check what you get in `response.text` - maybe there will be explanation what was the problem.